# Error running bernoulli example of Stan in julia

Tags: julia, stan

I'm trying to run the bernoulli example that is 
[here](https://github.com/goedman/Stan.jl/tree/master/Examples/Mamba/Bernoulli) using cmdstan2.17.1

however when I run the **bernoulli.jl** file in atom, after changing the

```
CmdStanDir="/CMDSTAN_HOME"
```

to the path where I created the .bash file, it gives me this error:

An error occurred while compiling the Stan program.

`Please check your Stan program in variable 'bernoulli' and the contents of /Users/panky/Desktop/Uni/IO/T2/tmp/bernoulli_build.log.`

Buy when I go to that file it appears this:

`make: *** No rule to make target '/Users/panky/Desktop/Uni/IO/T2/tmp/bernoulli'.  Stop.`

What does it means? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It means that it did not find the correct makefile. What is `CmdStanDir` set to and what exactly did you call in Julia to get that error message?

Comment: CmdStanDir is the directory where I have the folder of CmdStan and I get that error in this line: ' rc, sim1 = stan(stanmodel, bernoullidata, ProjDir, diagnostics=false, CmdStanDir="/Users/panky/Downloads") '

Comment: I believe it should be `CmdStanDir = "/Users/panky/Downloads/CmdStan"` so that it points to the root of the directory for CmdStan.

Comment: Apparently you need 50 reputation to comment, so Brian Parbhu, who's working on upgrading Stan.jl to modern Julia standards, asked me to comment for him:  check what path CMDSTAN_HOME is set to with the function `CMDSTAN_HOME = set_cmdstan_home!("path")`

He should print CMDSTAN_HOME in the REPL.

If he installed CmdStan with Homebrew or Linuxbrew he needs to check his Cellar for the location.  Then print it in the REPL to double check

Comment: I did that and added the directory with `CMDSTAN_HOME = set_cmdstan_home!("/Users/panky/Desktop")` and the checked it was correct, and now it gives another error: `ERROR: LoadError: Return code = -3` . I also tried `CmdStanDir = "/Users/panky/Downloads/CmdStan"` and the error changes to `LoadError: [91mchdir /Users/panky/Downloads/CmdStan: no such file or directory (ENOENT)`

Answer (score 1):

Please set your `CMDSTAN_HOME =` to the path where your `CmdStan` program lives. Right now it is set to `("/Users/panky/Desktop")` , which is pointing to your Desktop